# Use chromedriver quit() and cloesd(), why have zombie chrome process

Tags: docker, process, selenium-chromedriver

I enabled a jar package in the centos image, used selenium chromedriver to get the browser link, and after I finished using it, I used **close()** method and **quit()** method, but after the program accepted it, there were still many **chrome zombie processes**.

**chromedrive version 99**

**centos8**

**selenium4.7.2**

I also used to get Chromedrive’s pid to kill it, but it didn’t work

```java
...
        WebDriver driver = null;
        List<Integer> pids = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(service, desiredCapabilities);
            Integer port = service.getUrl().getPort();
            pids = GetChromePidFromPort(port);
            log.info("detected chrome process id " + pids);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
            driver.get(url);
            log.info("drive task is done, sleep :" + duration + " ms");
            Thread.sleep(duration);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            log.info("chrome download png error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.close();
                driver.quit();
                if (!pids.isEmpty()) {
                    killPid(pids);
                }
            }
        }
```

```java
    private static List<Integer> GetChromePidFromPort(Integer port) throws IOException {
        List<Integer> pidList = new ArrayList<>();
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i:" + port);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("chrome")) {
                int pid = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\s+")[1]);
                System.out.println("PID: " + pid);
                pidList.add(pid);
            }
        }
        return pidList;
    }
```

[image: process image]

Comment: I solved this problem. Just add --init  in docker run image ```docker run -d --init ```

Answer (score 0):

perfect, by adding the "init: true" command to my docker-compose.yml this eliminates all zombie processes without going through a docker run. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#init